# Regex: remove strings after slash just when they are more than one word

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

How to remove string after slash just when there are more than one word in the string? In specific, consider the following string:

```
    0      1     2        0       1      2   3   
 CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS
```

All the characters after slash should be removed because there are 4 words (HOPITAL, CENTRALE, DE, SOINS) and the limit is just one. Then the result is:
`CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL`

On the other hand, we have the following string:

```
   0     1     2    3  0
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20/20
```

`20` this time has to be kept because it is just one word (`\b[A-Za-z0-9]\b`). Then, the `/` slash should be replaced by empty space. The result should look like the following:
`HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20 20`

Suppose the following test set:

```
CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS
ELEMENTARY/INSTITUTION
FOUNDATION INSTITUTION/FUNDATION DEL INSTITUTO
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20/20
```

The result should be the following:

```
CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL
ELEMENTARY INSTITUTION
FOUNDATION INSTITUTION
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20 20
```

Overall, just keep the strings after slash just when it is one word and add an space where the slash was located. Otherwise, remove the strings after slash

I have tried this regex so far, but not working:
`(?:[\/])([A-Z0-9]*\b)(?!\b[A-Z]*)|[^\/]*$`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
rx = r'/(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+\W*$)?'
strs = ['CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL/HOPITAL CENTRALE DE SOINS','ELEMENTARY/INSTITUTION','FOUNDATION INSTITUTION/FUNDATION DEL INSTITUTO','HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20/20']
for s in strs:
    print( re.sub(rx, lambda x: "" if x.group(1) else " ", s) )
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/nJDur4). Output:

```
CENTRAL CARE HOSPITAL
ELEMENTARY INSTITUTION
FOUNDATION INSTITUTION
HAPPY SPRING BREAK 20 20
```

The regex is `/(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+\W*$)?`, see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/obFjA8/2). It matches:

- `/` - a slash
- `(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+\W*$)?` - an optional capturing group #1 that matches

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\W+\w+)+` - 1+ sequences of 1+ non-word chars followed with 1+ word chars
  - `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: I'd like to confirm: `(?:[^\w\n]+\w+)` this section you are checking for patterns such as ` abc` (space and a word) unlimited times and then check `[^\w\n]*$` any trailing spaces until the end of the string. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @JuanPerez `(?:\W+\w+)+\W*$` is matches 1+ sequences of 1+ non-word + 1+ word chars (that is, at least 1 word separated with non-word chars) and there can be any amount of non-word chars at the end of the string. `\w` matches letters, digits, `_` and some more Unicode chars in Python 3.x, `\W` matches the reverse set.